# How to understand the following linear mixed model?

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, glmm

I wonder how to understand the following mixed effect model.
$$y_{ij}|b_i \sim N(\mu+b_i+\beta_j,\sigma^2), \ \text{where} \ b_i \sim N(0,\sigma_b^2)$$
for $i=1,2,....,M, \ j=1,2,...,N$

What is the fixed effect and what is the random effect?  Can I write it in a matrix form? Why is it conditioned on $b_i$(I assume it's a random term?). If I remove the condition, how would the distribution of $y_{ij}$ be?

Comment: Where did you see this equation ? It looks ambiguous to me.

Comment: Why is it ambiguous?

Comment: This is confusing to me because I can't tell what $\gamma_i$ is. The fact that there is a value of $\gamma_i$ and $b_i$ for every group $i$ makes it look like these parameters are confounded/jointly unidentifiable ...

Comment: @BenBolker: I suspect that it is a simple misuse of notation. Probably because it was "estimated"  and now all "Greeks" are in the expected value.

Comment: ... so we should replace $\gamma_i$ with $b_i$? (This does reinforce @keepAlive's suggestion that we get the source for this equation, in case there have been transcription errors ...)

Comment: Pretty much. It obviously works fine after that change. (Bonus point: Also it makes my answer correct and I don't want to delete it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I strongly prefer using $\gamma$ or $u$ instead of $b$ when using "random effects" notation. Otherwise, if we accidentally capitalise something we might do a mistake. I don't understand why someone thought using $\beta$ and $b$ was a great convention...)

So, a standard "fixed-effects model" with normal errors would be:
$y = X\beta + \epsilon$, translating to: $y \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2I)$.

Now we extend this to a mixed-effects model with a $q$-length vector $u$ of random effects such that $u \sim N(0, \sigma^2 D)$ and an associated model matrix $Z$ (with $Z$ being of dimensions $n \times q$). By doing that we have the mixed-effects model: $y = X\beta + Zu + \epsilon$, translating to: $y \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2(I + ZDZ^T))$ or if we condition on $u$, translating to: $y|u \sim N(X\beta + Zu, \sigma^2I)$.

As you see, removing the conditioning on $u$ simply brought us back to "square one"; we have once again two sources of variation: one for the error term $\epsilon$ itself as well as one from the "random component" that is encoded in $Z$ and has distribution $N(0, \sigma^2 D)$.

I would recommend looking at some "easy" textbooks like: Faraway's "*[Extending the Linear Model with R](https://julianfaraway.github.io/faraway/ELM/)*" or West et al.'s "*[Linear Mixed Models: A Practical Guide Using Statistical Software](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ebwest/almmussp.html)*" (see Sect. 2.2 on the "*Specification of LMMs*" particularly). After building some familiarity with the subject a short paper like [*Conditional and Marginal Models: Another View*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-19/issue-2/Conditional-and-Marginal-Models-Another-View/10.1214/088342304000000305.full) (2004) by Lee and Nelder can help you appreciate more nuanced aspects of conditioning.

Comment: I think $\beta$ vs $b$ was chosen because Greek letter = parameter, Roman (lowercase) letter = random variable (yes, I know ϵ is also a random variable, but that's a special case)

Comment: Fair, you are too wise as always, but that doesn't mean it can't get confusing. Plus $\gamma$ is used too. (e.g. in Faraway's book)

Comment: @BenBolker: I edited to $u$, thanks for raising that point. ($u$ is used in West et al. book.)

Comment: Thanks. And now (fun fun): Doug Bates uses $b$ to denote "regular" random effects and $u$ for "spherized" random effects (i.e. transformed to the space where they are iid $\sim N(0,1)$ ...)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will take a look at it,

Comment: @BenBolker: I am dead. :)

Comment: @user10386405: I am glad I could help. As commented in the main question, mostly likely there is a bit of notation abuse involved in the original equation. I think after checking some of the book chapters mentioned you likely suspect that yourself too.

Comment: I edited it. Actually, $\gamma$ should be replaced by $b_i$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Great, thank you for coming back and fixing it.